# How to implement pagination with Apache Olingo V2?

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I need to use Apache Olingo V2 to implement an API using pagination. This means that I need to 
provide a simple URL for a collection of entities supporting basic $top and $skip operators,
just like in the example below:

https://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$top=5&$skip=3

I am not using the Annotation Processor extension or the JPA Processor Extension, so they are
not an option for implementing this pagination.

I checked the [Olingo V2 Server documentation](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/index.html#olingo-for-server-usage) but could not find an example for implementing pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using the `Annotation Processor extension` or `JPA Processor extension` you would have implemented/extended `ODataSingleProcessor`. You can retrieve the $skip and $top value from the URL from `GetEntitySetUriInfo` type argument and utilize to fetch data accordingly.

Below is the sample code for the same, you might want to do null checks and other sensitization.

```
@Override
public ODataResponse readEntitySet(GetEntitySetUriInfo uriInfo, String contentType) throws ODataException {

        int skipValue = uriInfo.getSkip();
        int topValue = uriInfo.getTop();

        URI serviceRoot = getContext().getPathInfo().getServiceRoot();
        ODataEntityProviderPropertiesBuilder propertiesBuilder = EntityProviderWriteProperties
                .serviceRoot(serviceRoot);

        List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        // fetch data from the datasource considering the skip and top values 
        // one example could be SELECT * FROM table LIMIT topValue OFFSET skipValue
        // fill in the data variable

        return EntityProvider.writeFeed(contentType, uriInfo.getStartEntitySet(), data, propertiesBuilder.build());

    }
```